# Matlab calculating with Excel cells

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to calculate with values from a excel which i transformed from a txt file.

My code is:

```
clc, clear

data = readtable('C:\Users\Steffen\Desktop\Masterarbeit\splithopskinsbar_15_02_measurements\Ergebnisse_07_03_Probe_NEU_18x13_18x10_18x9\07_03_Probe_NEU_18x13_18x10_18x9\Steffen_Runkel_Neu003.txt');
writetable(data, 'Steffen_Runkel_Neu003.xlsx'); %erstellen der excel
A=readcell('Steffen_Runkel_Neu003.xlsx');  %read of excel
Count_lines=size(A);  %count lines of matrix

CH_1=(A(2:Count_lines(1),2)); %definieren der WERTE
CH_2=(A(2:Count_lines(1),3)); %definieren der WERTE
time=(A(2:Count_lines(1),1)); %definieren der WERTE

CH_1_tranformed=str2double(CH_1);
CH_2_tranformed=str2double(CH_2);
time_transformed=str2double(time);

for i=1:Count_lines-1
    CH_1_tranformed(i,1)=(CH_1_tranformed(i,1)/100000)*10^-6;
    CH_2_tranformed(i,1)=(CH_2_tranformed(i,1)/100000)*10^-6;
end



y=CH_1_tranformed(1:Count_lines-1);
x=time(1:Count_lines-1);

plot(x,y);
```

the error which i get is
"Warning: Column headers from the file were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers before creating variable names for the
table. The original column headers are saved in the VariableDescriptions property.
Set 'VariableNamingRule' to 'preserve' to use the original column headers as table variable names.

**Error using plot
Invalid data argument.
Error in SHPB (line 26)
plot(x,y);"**

so I'cant plot it...

Comment: Are `CH_1_tranformed` and `time` cell arrays?  You can't plot cell arrays. [Error using plot, invalid data argument](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/308634-error-using-plot-invalid-data-argument#answer_240233)

Answer (score 0):

Your readcell statement creates a cell array. You might try using readmatrix  instead or use curly braces to to data out of cell array , e.g.,

```
CH_1=(A{2:Count_lines(1),2})
```